# Do field automorphisms of a character imply outer automorphisms of the group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Apologies for the imprecise wording of the title.

In studying the basic representation theory of finite groups, I've been struck by a pair of phenomena present in every example I've worked with but not mentioned in any texts I've studied. I am wondering if either or both of these phenomena is true in general, or perhaps true under some assumptions that are usually satisfied for small groups.

Phenomenon #1: We are given a finite group $G$ and a representation $\rho:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ on a complex vector space $V$, with character $\chi$.  Suppose $\chi(a)$ is an algebraic irrational, say $\alpha$, for some conjugacy class $a$ of $G$.  Then for any conjugate $\alpha'$ of $\alpha$ (i.e. another root of $\alpha$'s minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$), there exists a conjugacy class $a'$ of $G$, of the same size as $a$, such that $\chi(a')=\alpha'$.

Phenomenon #2: Furthermore, there is an outer automorphism of $G$ that carries $a$ to $a'$.

> Are these patterns at all general? If so, what assumptions are needed for them to hold?  If not, what are some counterexamples?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried looking at groups $G$ with $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ trivial, such as $S_n$?

Comment: @Alex But all the characters of $S_n$ are rational.

Comment: @Ted Yes, I just looked that up. But that's the only class of groups with no outer automorphisms I can think of.

Comment: The outer automorphism group of any nonabelian simple group is complete - i.e. it has trivial outer automorphism group.

Comment: @DerekHolt - why is that?

Comment: @DerekHolt - actually I think that's not true. I'm pretty sure $PSL(2,7)=GL(3,2)$ has an outer automorphism. Thinking of it as the automorphism group of the Fano plane, an outer automorphism follows from the self-duality of the plane. If $\phi$ bijects the points and lines in an incidence-structure-preserving way and $g\in GL(3,2)$ is an automorphism of the plane, then $g\mapsto \phi\circ g\circ \phi^{-1}$ is an outer automorphism of the group.

Comment: @DerekHolt - in fact, I think $A_n$ usually has an outer automorphism: conjugation by a transposition in $S_n$.

Comment: @Ben - The claim isn't that the outer automorphism group of a nonabelian simple group is trivial; it's that the outer automorphism group itself has trivial outer automorphism group.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense. But why would that be?

Comment: http://www.researchgate.net/publication/231820289_ALL_GROUPS_ARE_OUTER_AUTOMORPHISM_GROUPS_OF_SIMPLE_GROUPS Does this paper contradict Derek's comment?

Comment: Aside: a reference for @DerekHolt's claim is Joseph Rotman, *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups*, Theorem 7.14. (Looking at the 4th edition, this is on pp. 162-163.)

Comment: @AlexanderGruber - I believe it is possible for the paper to agree with the claim. If every group (that is not already the outer automorphism group of an *abelian* simple group) is a homomorphic image of a complete group, then they can both be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#1 is true.  If $a$ has order $n$, then by conjugation, we may assume that $\rho(a)$ is diagonal with $n$th roots of unity on the diagonal. Thus $\alpha = \chi(a)$ is a sum of $n$th roots of unity.  If $\alpha'$ is a conjugate of $\alpha$, then $\sigma(\alpha) = \alpha'$ for some $\sigma \in$ Gal($\mathbb{Q}(\mu)/\mathbb{Q}$) (where $\mu$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity).  We must have $\sigma(\mu) = \mu^k$ for some $k$ prime to $n$, in which case $\sigma$ sends all $n$th roots of unity to their $k$th powers.  Then $\rho(a^k)$ is also diagonal with all entries from $\rho(a)$ raised to the $k$th power. Hence $\chi(a^k) = \alpha'$.

The conjugacy classes of $a$ and $a^k$ have the same size because the $k$th power map and the $k^{-1}$ (mod $n$) power map are inverse maps between the two conjugacy classes.

#2 seems too good to be true, although I don't have a counterexample at hand.  It would imply that any group having a non-rational character would have an outer automorphism.

Comment: Take $G=PGL(2,7)$, which has no outer automorphisms and has two non-rational characters.